# NSTextStorage appendAttributedString: uncaught exception

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, nstextstorage

I'm trying to make an irc client. I keep one NSTextView object and i have a container class holding a NSTextStorage object. I use NSTextView's layoutManager to replace NSTextStorage objects every time user clicks on a "channel button". Text stored is in form of NSAttributedString because i want parts of text with different color.

The way i store NSAttributedString inside NSTextStorage is i get the pointer from the container object and use appendAttributedString on it.

And i'm getting an uncaught exception in NSLog and no break. Can you help me figure out what's wrong?

```
2015-09-14 08:25:49.776 ircX[3248:128903] *** -[NSConcreteTextStorage attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:]: Range or index out of bounds
2015-09-14 08:25:49.780 ircX[3248:128903] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9974503c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff99c0176e objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff99744eed +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff939c7d77 -[NSConcreteTextStorage attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:] + 127
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff94e05ffc -[NSTextView(NSSharing) setSelectedRanges:affinity:stillSelecting:] + 2525
    5   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff939a53af -[NSLayoutManager textStorage:edited:range:changeInLength:invalidatedRange:] + 423
    6   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff939c7291 -[NSTextStorage _notifyEdited:range:changeInLength:invalidatedRange:] + 152
    7   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff939c6d93 -[NSTextStorage processEditing] + 198
    8   UIFoundation                        0x00007fff939c6c98 -[NSTextStorage edited:range:changeInLength:] + 312
    9   Foundation                          0x00007fff925935e3 -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:] + 330
    10  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff939c87c1 __71-[NSConcreteTextStorage replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:]_block_invoke + 52
    11  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff939c8703 -[NSConcreteTextStorage replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:] + 136
    12  ircX                                0x000000010000b68b -[IRCWindow addData:] + 3371
    13  ircX                                0x000000010000195f -[ViewController updateTextView] + 527
    14  Foundation                          0x00007fff9259f953 __NSFireTimer + 95
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff996982e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff99697f73 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1059
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9970b53d __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 301
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff99653608 __CFRunLoopRun + 2024
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff99652bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    20  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff962a956f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
    21  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff962a92ea ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
    22  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff962a912b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    23  AppKit                              0x00007fff94d6c8ab _DPSNextEvent + 978
    24  AppKit                              0x00007fff94d6be58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
    25  AppKit                              0x00007fff94d61af3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
    26  AppKit                              0x00007fff94cde244 NSApplicationMain + 1832
    27  ircX                                0x00000001000020b2 main + 34
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff8ec045c9 start + 1
)
```

Comment: The error message says that while calling `attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:` either the index or the range is out of bounds, so check the values

Comment: Well i know for fact these values will be faulty. Debuggers don't lie. The thing is i never messed with indexes or ranges in first place. I just use appendAttributedString which works perfectly but goes faulty when i try to submit to other NSTextStorage objects and switch them. Can you think of an underlying cause to that?

Comment: Could be. The information you provided is too less to know more.

Comment: Hard to say what's causing the raise, but I would suggest a somewhat different design anyway.  Don't swap different NSTextStorage objects in and out; that's a weird thing to do.  Keep NSAttributedStrings in your container object, and swap new content into the existing text storage by doing -beginEditing, -setAttributedString, and -endEditing.  Re: your comment above, though, you clearly **do** do something with ranges; your `-[IRCWindow addData:]` method calls `-[NSConcreteTextStorage replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:]` according to the backtrace.  I'd look at the range there.

Comment: @BenHaller i am pretty sure my design is rushed and probably the main reason causing this. And about the index/range thing i guess all those calls are called by the appendAttributedString: method (which is the only thing i am calling) and probably uses default values to throw a string at the end of everything else.

Comment: Very odd that the backtrace shows you calling `-[NSConcreteTextStorage replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString:]` directly, then.  Shrug.

Comment: appendAttributedString: calls replaceCharactersInRange:withAttributedString: without a new stack frame (tail call).